# Nokogiri - Works with XML, not so much with HTML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm having an issue getting Nokogiri to work properly. I'm using version 1.4.4 with Ruby 1.9.2.

I have both libxml2 libxslt installed and up to date. When I run a Ruby script with XML, it works great.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))
doc = doc.css("name").each do |node|
    puts node.text
end
```

Enter into the CL, run `ruby test.rb`, returns

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

And the crowd goes wild.
I tweak a few things, make a few adjustments to the code...

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://domain.tld"))
doc = doc.css("p").each do |node|
    puts node.text
end
```

Back to CL, `ruby test.rb`, returns... nothing! Just a new, empty line.

Is there any reason that it will work with an XML file, but not HTML?

Comment: Some debugging questions: Have you checked to see if your .each block is iterating? Adding a `puts 1` in there will tell us if the problem is in obtaining the `p` nodes or with populating them. Also, have you checked to make sure doc is getting populated? This information will help determine the issue.

Comment: Here comes the "noob" questions...
How would I go about seeing if the doc is populating? 
I replaced `puts node.text` with `puts 1` and I didn't get any output.

Comment: You can do a `puts doc` and it will tell you if `doc` is nil or not.

Comment: Still getting a whole lot of nothing...
[No returns.](http://cl.ly/5yij)

Comment: Please supply the real URL you're testing against.

Comment: http://columbus.craigslist.com/pho
http://reddit.com
http://google.com
http://stackoverflow.com
etc...

Answer (score 5):

To debug this sort of problem we need more information from you. Since you're not giving a working URL, and because we know that Nokogiri works fine for this sort of problem, the debugging falls on you.

Here's what I would do to test:

In IRB:

1. Do you get output when you do: `open('http://whateverURLyouarehiding.com').read`
2. If that returns a valid document, what do you get when you wrap the previous open statement in `Nokogiri::HTML(...)`. That needs to preserve the `.read` in the previous line too, so Nokogiri is receiving the body of the page, NOT an IO stream.
3. Try #2 above, but remove the `.read`. That will tell if there's a problem with Nokogiri reading an IO stream, though I seriously doubt it has a problem since I use it all the time. At that point I'd suspect a problem on your system.
4. If you're getting a document in #2 and #3, then the problem could be in your accessor; I suspect what you're looking for doesn't exist.
5. If it does exist, then check the value of `doc.errors` after Nokogiri parses the document. It could be finding errors in the document, and, if so, they'll be captured there.

Comment: Whenever I ran your test in IRB, with any url, I'd get back:  
    `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http://columbus.craigslist.org/pho/
    from (irb):1:in 'initialize'
    from (irb):1:in 'open'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'`

However, I was messing around and commented out some of the code, to where it was just   
    `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://any-url"))
    puts doc`
It would return the doctype and the first instance of `<!-- html comment -->`

Comment: The first error is because you didn't `require 'open-uri'`. Open-URI modifies `open` to understand what to do with URLs.

Comment: The result from `puts doc` looks like you're not getting a full document back if you only got two lines. Retry #1 and #2, but make sure you type `require 'open-uri'` BEFORE you try to open the URL. And, I use Nokogiri and Open-URI all the time to hit craigslist for music equipment and it works fine. I'll look into it more when I get home tonight.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to rebuild libxml2 from source. The CentOS rmp version was really outdated and didn't play nice with Nokogiri 1.4.4. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ugh, CentOS. I fight with it daily.

Comment: I had the exactly same problem but the .read method works really well for me.